# C# + Access DB: Simple operations in an extra .cs?

Tags: c#, function

For a reason I can't use my MySQL-DB, so I switched to a Access DB.

I wanted to have some small functions that just do simple Queries like SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT.

I followed this small code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

class Csharp_Access
{
    public void Csharp_Access_Datenbank()
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
        Data Source=C:\data.mdb");
        con.Open();

        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tabelle1";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
        }
    }
```

When I just Copy&Paste it, this code works perfectly.
So I decided to but that code into a "dbFunctions.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AquadoServerTool
{
    class dbFunctions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Funktion, um eine Abfrage auszuführen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="QueryStr">SQL-String</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static OleDbDataReader QueryString(string QueryStr)
        {
            // string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM seriennummer";

            // Verbindung zur Datenbank aufbauen
            OleDbConnection con = null;
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(GlobalVar.strAccessConn);
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryStr, con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            // while (dr.Read())
            // {
            //     MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
            // }

            con.Close();

            return dr;
        }
    }

}
```

For testing, I made a little button if that works:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbDataReader dr = dbFunctions.QueryString("SELECT * FROM seriennummer;");

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dr[1].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
```

Yeah, now click that button to oblivion!
But I get the error, that Read() won't work, because it has been already closed.

Is my code simply wrong or did I just forgot something?

Greetings,
Trollwut

Comment: I think you might need `.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` behaviour, so that the connection closes when you close the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you first close the connection, and *then* try to read from the `DataReader`. You have to keep the connection open to read.

---

You could create a wrapper around the `DataReader` that implements `IDisposable` and closes the connection for you.

**Simple example:**

```
class Wrapper : IDisposable
{
    public OleDbDataReader Reader { get { return reader; } }
    private OleDbConnection connection;

    public Wrapper(OleDbConnection connection, string QueryStr)
    { 
        this.connection = connection; 
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryStr, connection);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}

class dbFunctions
{
    public static OleDbDataReader QueryString(string QueryStr)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GlobalVar.strAccessConn);
        con.Open();
        return new Wrapper(con, QueryStr);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dr = dbFunctions.QueryString("SELECT * FROM seriennummer;"))
        while (dr.Reader.Read())
            MessageBox.Show(dr[1].ToString());
}
```

---

Another way is to simple return the data via a `DataTable`.

```
class dbFunctions
{
    public static DataTable QueryString(string QueryStr)
    {
        var result = new DataTable();
        using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GlobalVar.strAccessConn))
        {
            con.Open();
            using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryStr, con))
                result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return result;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = dbFunctions.QueryString("SELECT * FROM seriennummer;");
    foreach(var row in data.Rows)
        MessageBox.Show(row[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you for that quick response. So that reader requires a connection... is there a way where i can get the results for that return?

Comment: Hi there again! I used your example for DataTable. `foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)` and then it worked. Thank you for that solution! My only worrying is... how do I use INSERT and UPDATE then? Or do they just return an empty return?

Comment: @Trollwut For `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, you would use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method of the `DbCommand`. It just returns an integer indicating how many rows were affected. I would create a second method just called `Execute` that returns that number.

Comment: @Trollwut If my answer worked for you, please vote up and accept my answer (einfach auf den Hacken clicken) :-)

Comment: Okay! I think that I can do that myself. Thank you again for help! Oh man, ich glaub ich hol mir erstmal BASIC für Dummies oder so...

Comment: Nun gut, habe nun mehr ein Problem. :) In der Zeile `MessageBox.Show(row[1].ToString());` sagt er mir nun: `Fehler 1 Indizierung mit [] kann nicht auf einen Ausdruck vom Typ "object" angewendet werden.` Bisher hat alles wunderbar geklappt - danke schon mal für die Hilfe! Nur wenn ich die Zeile nun so übernehme (was ich nun muss), spuckt er das aus. Hab schon rumprobiert, komme aber nicht drauf, wieso das nicht mehr klappt. Gestern noch spuckte er mir X MessageBoxes aus, heute der Fehler...

Comment: Die Lösung liegt meist einfach auf der Hand... habs in `foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)` umgeschrieben und es klappt. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `DataSet` instead of `DataReader`
`DataReader` needs connection open to read from it.